# Lock SQLite database when connecting

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a SQLite database that is saved on a network share and can be accessed by multiple users.
Now the schema of this database needs to be changed (by a self written program) and I need to make sure that during the update operation no other user can open the database (neither for writing nor for reading).
To my knowledge the `PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE` could be used to lock the database. Unfortunately the exclusive lock is only obtained when the first write operation is executed.
That means that in the time between opening the database, setting the locking mode and the first write operation a different user would be able to open the database.
Is there any way to obtain the exclusive lock on **opening** the database with System.Data.SQLite from C#?

**EDIT**
As you requested some code, here you go:

```cs
void UpdateDatabaseSchema(Boolean UpdateNeeded)
{
    // make sure that all SQLite* objects are disposed correctly by using-statement, otherwise database will not be closed correctly!
    using (var Connection = new SQLiteConnection("./Database.db"))
    using (var Command = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        Connection.Open();
        Command.CommandText = "PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE;";
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Command.CommandText = "PRAGMA locking_mode;";
        using (var DataReader = Command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (DataReader.Read())
            {
                var Test = DataReader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
        if (UpdateNeeded)
        {
            if (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Do you want to update the database schema?", "Update needed", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Users (Test TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously the reading of the locking mode is only there for debugging (and will be removed for productive code).
Now what happens if another user opens the same database - a tiny bit - later than the first user but is faster in clicking "Yes"? The first user will get an error because the schema has already been changed.
Yes, I could write the statement differently but this update is just an example, there might - and will - be more difficult queries in the future and I don't want to care about these race conditions in every command (at least if possible).
Hence I need to lock the database **on opening**.

@C Perkins:
- Handling the problem on file system basis is something I had not thought about, I'll have a look into that possibility, thanks for the input!
- Online docs also mentions "The first time the database is written, an exclusive lock is obtained and held." I know it is only released when the connection is closed, the problem is it is only *obtained* on the first write operation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Why not just move/copy the file to another location, perhaps to a local folder?  Update it locally.  Copy it back.  To prevent others from opening the database, set network access permissions on the file, even temporarily, then set them back afterward.  There are various ways to get the job done without worrying about settings in your code.

Comment: [Online docs](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode) explain that "When the locking-mode is set to EXCLUSIVE, the database connection never releases file-locks."  The behavior you describe is for NORMAL locking mode.  Are you certain that the connection is not being closed and reopened with different locking modes?  It is common to open and close a DB connection often throughout code.  How are you setting the pragma?  Are you using a SqliteConnectionStringBuilder object?  Show some code.

Comment: FYI, users are not notified when you update a question, even if you tag them in the text. You need to post a new *comment* that tags the user for them to be notified. I only happened upon this again when reviewing unanswered questions.

Comment: @CPerkins: Thanks for the info, I wasn't aware of that! Your solution works perfectly fine, thanks for that, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My testing indicates that an exclusive lock is obtained by executing any kind of database-changing command whether or not it actually makes a change.  In other words, the following two commands will end up obtaining an exclusive lock, but the `WHERE false` makes the command a null op.

```
//* The following only changes the mode, but does not lock the file
Command.CommandText = "PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE;";
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

try {
    using (var cmdLock = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        //* The following command will force an exclusive file lock to be obtained.
        //* Although 'WHERE false' will cause the actual UPDATE to fail,
        //*   the actual statement is valid SQL and will not cause an error. 
        cmdLock .CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET Test = 'bogus' WHERE false;";
        cmdLock .ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    //* Exclusive lock obtained
    //... free to do updates
} 
catch {
   MessageBox.Show("Failed to obtain exclusive lock, try again later.", "Lock failed")
}
```